# How set value for the UILabel by clicking the UIButton IOS7

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, uibutton

In my application have created a drop down Menu when user select the option form the menu the selected option must be visible in the `UILabel` box. For that i have one `UILabel` box inside that i have kept on `UIbutton` and i have changed the UIButton into down arrow symbol to user know the option is there.

When user click on the arrow a `UIView` comes as a `POPUP` like a drop down Menu inside the `UIView` i have kept the three UIButton if user select the button that particular button name as to appear in the `UILabel` box in the top. For that i have set the Tags for the Options UIButtons whenever user click option according to the tag it has to set the Value to `UILabel` i have tried this method its not working.

My code.

```
- (void) showPopView1
  {
    self.popup.alpha = 1;
   [self.popup setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150)];
  }
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
     [self showPopView1];
     if([sender tag] == 1){   
option.text = @"You Pressed Button 1";

     }
       else if([sender tag] == 2){
       option.text = @"You Pressed Button 2";      
   }
   }
```

I have used the above code to achieve that task its not working please tell me whether I'm doing the right or where I'm doing wrong . My Output Screen.

[image]

Comment: [btn setTitle:@"YOUR TITLE HERE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: It seems that you forgot to add action method for color buttons.

Comment: @Avt do i have to add action for all the options buttons

Comment: Yes, you need to add the target to trigger

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya please to tell i want to change the UIlabel name how this code will change the label text

Comment: @KumarKL can please tell me how to add that target trigger

Comment: you connect UILabel iboutlet in nib file?

Comment: ya i have connected the uilabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
     [self showPopView1];

     UIButton *red = (UIButton*)[self.popUp viewWithTag:1];
     [red addTarget:self action:@selector(colorSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     UIButton *blue = (UIButton*)[self.popUp viewWithTag:2];
     [red addTarget:self action:@selector(colorSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

-(void)colorSelected : (UIButton*)sender{

     if([sender tag] == 1){   
option.text = @"You Pressed Button 1";

     }
       else if([sender tag] == 2){
       option.text = @"You Pressed Button 2";      
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create outlet for your label, and after clicking on an option you will be able to set:

```
label.text = @"Selected value";
```

But actually, your solution is going against Human Interface Guideline. Ii is better to use UIPickerView for "combo box like" drop-down list. You can even simplify solution using UITextField + UIPickerView. You can set a custom view for text field instead of keyboard, and when you activate the text field - your custom view will appear nicely. You have to use property inputView in text field.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
// Set delegate and other configs for picker view
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```

After that when you select a text filed - picker view will swipe up just like default keyboard does. You just need to handle UIPickerView delegate and data source methods to fill it and catch the selection:

```
– numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
– pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:
– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:
– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

This methods should be implemented for correct behavior of picker view. And method

```
 – pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

will be called when you select any row in picker view, and you can set needed value for text field there:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected row is: %d", row];
}
```